# How can I emulate archive.org's "Save outlinks"-option with wget or similar?

Tags: curl, post, http-headers, wget

If you are logged in to archive.org and [archive a web page](https://web.archive.org/save/) there is an option *Save outlinks*:
[image: screen shot]

I looked through all http headers in one request with this checkbox checked and one request without it checked, and couldn't find any differences that corresponded to this checkbox between those two requests.

**I would like to emulate this checkbox using wget or similar and/or Java. How do I do that?**

Bonus point to anyone who can explain how one does to figure that out using the web inspector, an extension or similar.

Answer (score 1):

1. > and couldn't find any differences

   But there is a difference. Make requests with and without checkbox, right click on them, choose `Save all as HAR with content`. Diff it. (In *DevTools* it can be seen as well - at the bottom of "Headers" tab).

   With **`capture_outlinks=on`**:

   ```
   "postData": {
     "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "text": "url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&capture_outlinks=on",
     "params": [
       {
         "name": "url",
         "value": "https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F"
       },
       {
         "name": "capture_outlinks",
         "value": "on"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Without:

   ```
   "postData": {
     "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "text": "url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F",
     "params": [
       {
         "name": "url",
         "value": "https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Also you'll find a subsequent GET request to something like `https://web.archive.org/save/status/{job_id}?_t={timestamp}`. In response to it you'll find `application/json` with JSON with `outlinks` array in it, actually, `outlinks` array is present in both HARs. But when **`capture_outlinks=on`** there is also `resources` array.
3. The aforementioned request is initiated from a loaded script. This you can find out by searching for `save/status` in HARs or in *DevTools* in the "Initiator" tab.
4. The fact that the `job_id` is what it is you can confirm by searching for it's value in the same JSON and also you'll find it in the response to the initial `POST` to https://web.archive.org/save/https://stackoverflow.com/ inside a call to `watchJob()`

Maybe I missed something, but as I see it right now, you need to

- make a POST to https://web.archive.org/save/https://stackoverflow.com/ with form-urlencoded `url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&capture_outlinks=on`
- get `job_id` from the response somehow (regexp maybe)
- then, with the `job_id` you've found, make GET request to `https://web.archive.org/save/status/{job_id}?_t={timestamp}` (of course you'll need cookies, and possibly, generate a correct timestamp)

Comment: Thank you. What is this `HAR` acronym you are referring to? Are you using Chrome or Firefox (or something else)?

Comment: @d-b, I'm using Chrome, but you can save HARs in FF too. What stands for HAR I have no idea :)

Comment: Hmm, I suck at this...Would it be possible for you to create an extremely basic sample script for wget/curl (or any similar tool) with an example of how to use this? Could increase the reward if you like.

Comment: Will it OK for you to have a JS snippet to run from Chrome's console while on the archive.org and logged in? Not sure if I have time for anything more complex right now. But were have you stuck? Maybe I can guide you. And when we talk about scripts are we talking about `bash` or something else?

Comment: Bash or something like that would be ideal. Will include it in a cron job or similar. Great thanks :-)

Comment: @d-b, Sorry. It turns out that I'm not so fluent with bash either :). I'll need to read some docs. That would be interesting... But as I said I don't have much time, and just recently something came up and I don't have it at all. So I'll be able to revisit this question only in a week or two :-\ not sure you can wait so long.

Comment: No problem with waiting. That would be extremely helpful. Let me know if you like a bounty for your effort :-)

Comment: Made any progress? Thank you.